# Salt state.apply getting failed when run multiple times

Tags: salt-stack

We are trying to setup a proxy using salt state files.. 
Initially my proxy.sls file runs perfectly from master without any errors. When i run the same command again it gets failed.. 
I run the below command from salt-master 
**[root@omsstusaltmgmt ~]# salt "*proxy*" state.apply**

As i said initially it will be successful and when i run the same command it gets failed.. as below..

### **up_oms_st_proxy1:

```
      ID: git
Function: pkg.installed
  Result: False
 Comment: Unable to run command '[u'rpm', u'-qa', u'--queryformat', u'%{NAME}_|-%{EPOCH}_|-%{VERSION}_|-%{RELEASE}_|-%{ARCH}_|-(none)_|-%{INSTALLTIME}\n']' with the context '{u'timeout': None, u'with_communicate': True, u'shell': False, u'bg': False, u'stderr': -2, u'env': {'LC_NUMERIC': 'C', 'HTTP_PROXY': '216.203.5.248:9090', 'LC_CTYPE': 'C', 'LESSOPEN': '||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s', 'SSH_CLIENT': '10.139.65.217 49284 22', 'SELINUX_USE_CURRENT_RANGE': '', 'LOGNAME': 'root', 'USER'**
```

---

```
      **ID: unzip
Function: pkg.installed
  Result: False
 Comment: Unable to run command '[u'rpm', u'-qa', u'--queryformat', u'%{NAME}_|-%{EPOCH}_|-%{VERSION}_|-%{RELEASE}_|-%{ARCH}_|-(none)_|-%{INSTALLTIME}\n']' with the context '{u'timeout': None, u'with_communicate': True, u'shell': False, u'bg': False, u'stderr': -2, u'env': {'LC_NUMERIC': 'C', 'HTTP_PROXY':**
```

*When i manually goes into my salt-minion(proxy server) and restart the salt-minion this command(salt "*proxy*" state.apply get executed perfectly without failure *
I dont want to manually restart the minion when ever i required a deployment on proxy box..

Can anyone help me out here 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Below is the exact O/P for first two steps..

Comment: there should me further information in your output regarding the error, can you add it please?, also please show your top file configuration.